# Numpy multiarray failed to import (Win 10, Anaconda 3)

Tags: python, numpy

When using Anaconda 3 on Windows 10 with Visual Studio Code I keep getting the error `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

This happens pretty much everytime I open up Visual Studio Code. I can get it working for a couple hours, however long I'm using it for. Then after a couple of days it breaks again. I've tried using the conda terminal to uninstall and reinstall numpy with the command `conda uninstall numpy` followed with `conda install numpy` but it isn't changing anything. Thanks.